# Range property is not working ; not displaying corresponding cell value

Tags: excel, vba

this is my code, it shows error,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("z")) Is Nothing Then

        Cancel = True

      If ActiveCell = 0 Or ActiveCell = "" Then

        Target.Formula = Worksheets("Info Sheet").Range("S3:S100").Value & Now()

    End If
```

it will work on this -

```
Target.Formula = Worksheets("Info Sheet").Range("S3").Value & Now()
```

Comment: `.Range("S3:S100").Value.` is a 2D Variant array. You can't concatenate an array and `Now()`. What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: I would like to get the result like , if i click the Z10 the value ("S10")+Now() , if i click Z11 then value ("S10")+Now()

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to get the result like , if i click the Z10 the value ("S10")+Now() , if i click Z11 then value ("S11")+Now() <sup>1</sup>

Use the following:

```
Target.Value = Me.Range("S" & Target.Row).Value & Now()
```

If `Worksheets("Info Sheet")` is a different sheet than the one containing the code, use:

```
Target.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info Sheet").Range("S" & Target.Row).Value & Now()
```

<sup>1</sup> I'm assumimg you meant `S11` instead of `S10` twice.